# how to render partial view conditionally

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

i'm having a view (parent view) consisting of a child view (partial view)
as below,

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("_partialViewName",Model);}

@(Html.X().Panel().
        Items(Html.X().Container().ID("cntrGenerateReportResult")
          )
    )
```

is it possible to show/hide (Render) the partial view conditionally based on 
a property value from Model

i tried,

```
@if(Model.Type != "RER")
{ 
    Html.RenderPartial("_partialViewName", Model); 
}
```

but not getting the panel below rendered..

Comment: Could you show the partial view Code?

Answer (score 1):

If Type has value 'RER' it should be rendered:

```
    @if(Model.Type.Trim() == "RER")
    { 

    }
    else
    {
     Html.RenderPartial("_partialViewName", Model); 
    }
```

you have to make sure that Type is not "RER" otherwise it should work

Comment: if `Type` has value `"RER"` i dont want to render the partial view

Comment: ok so then if its not RER it should work debug and check in view if its no RER, its coming RER i am sure

Answer (score 0):

If your main view is bound with model & partial view also required a model then bind both of the model in partial view using "Tuple". Send partial view name through ViewBag to the view.

```
@if (@ViewBag.PartialView != null && @ViewBag.PartialView!= "")
{
    @Html.Partial(@ViewBag.PartialView)
}
```

You can use model for main view using Model.Item1/2/3/4 directly.

But disadvantage of this is that you have to bind a blank partial view when you don't need it.