# After submitting the form, partial view( including a checkboxlist according to the id selected from a dropdownlist )does not appear on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my code below when I select an item( a Congress) from DropDownList it brings sessions of the congress correctly. However;
1-When I submit the form, the chosen DropdownList item comes, but I also need to show the partial view with the checkbox list and its checked items.

Thank you very much if you can help.

[Select items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfNk8.png)
My dropdownlist

```
        <span class="label-input100">Katılmak İstediğiniz Eğitim *</span>
        <div>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FKKongreId, ViewBag.dgr as SelectList, "Katılmak istediğiniz eğitimi seçin", new
       {
           id = "KongreList",
           @class = "selection-2"
       })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FKKongreId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
    </div>
```

Div for showing the partial view

```
    <div id="partialPlaceHolder" class="wrap-input100" style='display:none'>
    </div>
```

Javascript code for sending the Id of the selected item

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#KongreList").on("change", function () {
            var url = '@Url.Action("GetOturum", "Home")' + "?KongreId=" + $(this).val();

            $("#partialPlaceHolder").load(url, function () {
                $('#partialPlaceHolder').fadeIn('fast');
            })
        });
    });
```

My Partial view results from Home Controller

```
public PartialViewResult GetOturum(int KongreId)
        {
            KongreDbEntities db = new KongreDbEntities();

            BasvuruViewModel model = new BasvuruViewModel();

            List<Oturum> oturums = new List<Oturum>();

            oturums = db.Oturums.Where(x => x.FKKongreId == KongreId).ToList();

            model.OturumList = oturums;

            return PartialView("_GetOturum", model);
        }
```

_GetOturum.cshtml

```
<table id="checkbox" style="margin-top: 6px;">

    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.OturumList.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.OturumList[i].IsChecked, new { @class = "checkbox" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.OturumList, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                <label style="font-family: Poppins-Medium">@Model.OturumList[i].OturumAd</label>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OturumList[i].Id)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OturumList[i].OturumAd)

                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OturumList[i].OturumBaslangic)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OturumList[i].OturumBitis)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

[postback part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9U0t.png)

Comment: Since you're using ASP.NET MVC, I think instead of leveraging jQuery to display the partial html, you may instead want to use an actual MVC partial view (`@Html.Partial()`) and conditionally display it with Razor syntax.  Here's an example of conditionally rendering an MVC partial view: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23006057/how-to-render-partial-view-conditionally/46951491.  And more info on MVC partial views: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/partial-view-in-asp.net-mvc

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Can you show me how to adjust my code to @Html.Partial()? I have trouble doing it.